# Ошибка ts при сборке проекта yarn run build

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, nextjs, yarn

Помогите пожалуйста)
Появляется ошибка при сборке проекта yarn run build, при dev режиме всё без ошибок.
Тут логика такая, на странице есть много карточек и по каждой из них можно кликнуть и тебя перекинет на страницу с айдишником в урле этой карточки. getProjects получает этот айдишник, делает запрос и возвращает нужный объект передавая его в Item пропсами.
Использую Next 14.1 и ts 5

Ещё ругается на params где передаются пропсы, но там я тоже без понятия как можно исправить.

```
В типе "Props" отсутствуют следующие свойства из типа "{ id: number; title: string; url: string; }": id, title, urlts(2739)
item.tsx(6, 3): Ожидаемый тип поступает из свойства "params", объявленного здесь в типе "IntrinsicAttributes & Props"

.next/types/app/portfolio/[id]/page.ts:8:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<typeof import("E:/My projects/web-studio/src/app/portfolio/[id]/page"), "metadata" | "default" | "config" | "generateStaticParams" | "revalidate" | "dynamic" | "dynamicParams" | ... 6 more ... | "generateViewport", "">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'getProjects' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(id: number) => Promise<Props>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

   6 |
   7 | // Check that the entry is a valid entry
>  8 | checkFields<Diff<{
     |             ^
   9 |   default: Function
  10 |   config?: {}
  11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function
error Command failed with exit code 1.

import Layout from '@/components/layout/layout';
import Item from '@/components/Item/item';
import { PHOTOS_API_URL } from '@/utils/prepareData';

type Project = {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  url: string;
};

type Props = {
  params: Project;
};

export async function getProjects(id: number): Promise<Props> {
  const res = await fetch(`${PHOTOS_API_URL}/${id}`);
  const projects = await res.json();

  return projects;
}

export default async function Card({ params }: Props) {
  const projects = await getProjects(Number(params.id));

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Item params={projects} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: export  у getProjects убери, все по идее наладится, не знаю почему так